# Изображения в tkinter пока идет логическое вычисление

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Изучаю **python 3** (и **tkinter**), необходимо реализовать следующую мысль:
    нужно выводить в окне картинку или какую-либо надпись пока у меня какое-то время идут некоторые вычисления, потом это окно нужно закрыть. Пример:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(text='Please wait').pack()
# здесь выполняется некий цикл от 5 до 30 сек
...
root.mainloop()
```

Подскажите, как это правильно сделать!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается, вместо **.mainloop()** надо использовать **.update()**.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Label(text='Please wait').pack()
root.update()
# здесь выполняется некий цикл от 5 до 30 сек
...
root.destroy()
```

Окно после цикла закрывается и программа дальше идет своим чередом

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего использовать многопоточность:

```
import time

from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Ничего не происходит')
label.pack()


def long_calculation(seconds):
    label.config(text='Ждём...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    label.config(text='Дождались!')


def start_thread():
    thread = Thread(target=long_calculation, args=(5,))
    thread.start()


b = Button(root, text='Запуск', command=start_thread)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter, как и большинство GUI-библиотек, не является потокобезопасным, поэтому вызывать в потоке `label.config()` - это очень плохая идея.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я для примера. Ему же надо производить какие-то вычисления, а это не обязательно связано с редактированием виджетов.

Comment: Я, видимо не достаточно объяснил свою хотелку. Пока программа ищет файл на компьютере, в окне должно быть написано "Ждемс", после того как файл найдется, первое окно должно закрыться и открыться основное окно для дальнейшей работы (с этим файлом).

Comment: Или все это может происходить в одном окне, просто надпись исчезает после поиска - не важно. Не очень я дружу с tkinter ))